# Change constructor's value with another function JS

Tags: javascript

I am working on the below task and can't find the solution. I have the constructor (Tree) and object created using it (theTree). Now I want to add new function (alter) that would change greeting value of the constructor (so of all new objects created with it) but also for existing objects. To be honest, I don't know how to get to the contructor's properties within that function. I will appreciate if you could take a look and advise where to start. This is what I got so far:

```
 function Tree(name) {
     this.name = name;
     this.greeting = "Hi";
 }

 var theTree = new Tree("Pine");
 theTree.greeting = "hello";

 var alter = function(constructor, greeting) {
 this.greeting = greeting;       
}
```

Comment: If you want a value to be shared by all instances, don't set it as a property of every instance.

Comment: Put `greeting` on the prototype. Remove `this.greeting =` from the constructor, and change the body of `alter` to `constructor.prototype.greeting = greeting;`. However, this will not change the `greeting` value of instances on which it has already been set directly. No-one knows what instances have been created, unless you keep track of them yourself somehow.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks! That works perfectly fine with prototype. It also changes the greeting value for the objects that were created before using that function, not for these that had the value set directly but it's fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Put `greeting` on the prototype. Remove `this.greeting =` from the constructor, and change the body of `alter` to `constructor.prototype.greeting = greeting;`.

However, this will not change the `greeting` value of instances on which it has already been set directly. No-one knows what instances have been created, unless you keep track of them yourself somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alter = function(tmpObject,greeting){
 tmpObject.greeting = greeting;
 console.log(tmpObject.greeting);

}
```

To alter function pass your constructor and greeting message.It will change.